# Frame automatic change in new xcode 6.0

Tags: xcode6

I have put a view in view controller and gives frame to it. when ever I run the application in xcode 5.1.1 it works fine. But in xcode 6.0 it shows correct frame in storyboard. But at runtime frame changed to (0, 0, 0, 0). I have not change the frame runtime but it change automatically. So Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean Xcode 6 or iOS 8?

Comment: it is the fault due to xcode 6. Because if I run app in ios 8 then it works well but when I run from xcode 6 it change the frame.